# Database query vs PHP require_once

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have developed a rather complicated web application that needs to query the database several times in each page in order to generate data tables that will be represented in HTML.
Because of that I created a module that every time a page is queried it loads up the data, creates the necessary HTML response and stores it for a specific amount of time in the server in order for the next visits (in the specified amount of time) no database calls are made, but PHP loads the generated file via the `require_once` function.

Do I earn in resources usage with this method or the data query is preferred from `require_once`?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: What you do is some good old *caching*. That's a perfectly viable thing to do. There's no absolute yes or no. If it helps you, great.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question - it's too broad. All this depends on how complex your query is, what's the table layout, how much data you have in the table, how big is the result set, are indexes used and so on. *If done properly*, caching the results should improve performance. Whether that makes any difference in your case is completely different thing. YMMV.

Comment: My slight concern with using require_once is that the generated file is a script that can be executed. However is this page shared between users? If no then possibly store it in a session variable (depending on size, etc). Suspect querying the db would be less efficient

Comment: There is nothing wrong with caching, but `require` is not designed for  that.

Comment: Are these queries actually causing performance issues? Using an included code file that your are changing periodically might be fragile in other ways. Is there not a mute traditional caching mechanism you can use... if you really need it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql queries use indexing for optmized retrieval of data. if your data will be static most of the time, not user specific, then its fine to use require_once. If you intend to scale up your application, you will have to optimize your database. Remember require_once has to access the disk every time a user requests a resource.